# Como agrupar datas de acordo com o dia da semana

Tags: php, sql

Bom, eu tenho uma tabela a qual tem uma coluna do `id` do usuário `user_id` e uma com datas. Gostaria de saber como agrupar e contar as datas as quais estao no formado. Exemplo: `07.06.14` nos respectivos dias da semana e de acordo com o usuário `user_id` que esta na linha das datas. 
Por exemplo:

```
  user_id |  data
  1          07.06.14
  1          07.06.14
  2          06.06.14
```

Deve retornar:

```
   O usuario 1 possui 2 datas no Sabado.
   O usuario 2 possui 1 data na Sexta.
```

Tentei criar 2 funcoes para isso, mas não deu certo:

```
function Get_weekday($d,$m,$y){
//Pega o dia da semana em ingles
$date = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m  , $d, $y));
//Traduz
if($date == "Monday"){return 4;}
if($date == "Tuesday"){return 3;}
if($date == "Wednesday"){return 2;}
if($date == "Thursday"){return 1;}
if($date == "Friday"){return 0;}
if($date == "Saturday"){return 0;}
if($date == "Sunday"){return 0;}
}
function count_entregas_per_date($func_id,$day){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(date) as data,date FROM entregas WHERE func_id =    '$func_id' GROUP BY date");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) // Armazena os funcionarios em um array
{
$dat = explode(".",$row['date']);
echo "Na data ". $row['date'] . " houveram " . $row['data']. " pedidos realizados por      "              . username_from_user_id($func_id). "
   .  E foi no dia de codigo " . 
Get_weekday($dat[0],$dat[1],$dat[2]). " </br>";

}}
```

Comment: Cada BD tem suas funções para manipular datas, procure a documentação do BD em questão para detalhes. Mas em todo o caso tente o EXTRACT da ANSI http://users.atw.hu/sqlnut/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html

Comment: Qual é a saída que obténs assim?

Comment: A data que está no banco de dados é aquela mencionada acima?? DD/MM/YYYY?? ou ta registrada com o padrão do banco YYYY/MM/DD, pois se tiver no formato padrão, te mando uma função que ele já te retorna tudo certinho direto do banco

Answer (score 3):

Utilize sempre campos `date` na sua tabela, e não campos `varchar` com dados do tipo `date`, pode trazer problemas futuros. Outro fator não utilize [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) ele é depreciado nas novas versões do [PHP](http://www.php.net/). Mesmo assim construi 3 exemplos: `mysql`, [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) e [`pdo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) veja logo abaixo:

**Exemplo:**

**1 ) Mysql (não recomendado)**

```php
<?php
    function GetSemana($date){
        list($d,$m,$y) = explode('.', $date);
        switch (strtolower(date('l', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m ,$d,$y))))
        {           
            case 'sunday': {
                return ' no domingo';
                break;
            }
            case 'monday': {
                return ' na segunda-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'tuesday': {
                return ' na ter&ccedil;a-feira';
                break;
            }           
            case 'wednesday': {
                return ' na quarta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'thursday': {
                return ' na quinta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'friday': {
                return ' na sexta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'saturday': {
                return ' no s&aacute;bado';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $conn  = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "senha");
             mysql_select_db("generics", $conn);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, data, count(user_id) as datacount FROM entregas GROUP BY user_id, data", $conn);
    while($item = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        echo '['.$item['data'].'] ';
        echo ' O usuario '.$item['user_id'];
        echo ' possui '.$item['datacount'];
        echo ' data'.((int)$item['datacount']>1?'s':'');
        echo GetSemana($item['databr']);
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

**2 ) Mysqli**

```php
<?php
    function GetSemana($date){
        list($d,$m,$y) = explode('.', $date);
        switch (strtolower(date('l', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m ,$d,$y))))
        {           
            case 'sunday': {
                return ' no domingo';
                break;
            }
            case 'monday': {
                return ' na segunda-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'tuesday': {
                return ' na ter&ccedil;a-feira';
                break;
            }           
            case 'wednesday': {
                return ' na quarta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'thursday': {
                return ' na quinta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'friday': {
                return ' na sexta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'saturday': {
                return ' no s&aacute;bado';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "senha", "generics");
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_id, data, count(user_id) as datacount FROM entregas GROUP BY user_id, data");
    while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

        echo '['.$item['data'].'] ';
        echo ' O usuario '.$item['user_id'];
        echo ' possui '.$item['datacount'];
        echo ' data'.((int)$item['datacount']>1?'s':'');
        echo GetSemana($item['databr']);
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

**3 ) PDO**

```php
<?php
    function GetSemana($date){
        list($d,$m,$y) = explode('.', $date);
        switch (strtolower(date('l', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m ,$d,$y))))
        {           
            case 'sunday': {
                return ' no domingo';
                break;
            }
            case 'monday': {
                return ' na segunda-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'tuesday': {
                return ' na ter&ccedil;a-feira';
                break;
            }           
            case 'wednesday': {
                return ' na quarta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'thursday': {
                return ' na quinta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'friday': {
                return ' na sexta-feira';
                break;
            }
            case 'saturday': {
                return ' no s&aacute;bado';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=generics", "root", "senha");
    $res = $pdo->query("SELECT user_id, data, count(user_id) as datacount FROM entregas GROUP BY user_id, data");
    foreach($res as $item){
        echo '['.$item['data'].'] ';
        echo ' O usuario '.$item['user_id'];
        echo ' possui '.$item['datacount'];
        echo ' data'.((int)$item['datacount']>1?'s':'');
        echo GetSemana($item['databr']);
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

**Obs:** *pode adaptar ao seu script.*

Comment: A realidade é que ele usa `mysql_*` a resposta deveria ser dada assim. Já agora fica a dica que pode utilizar [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) em vez de `mysql_*`, assim poderá manter o seu código.

Comment: A realidade dele tem que ser observada e se ele usa um algo ruim podemos alertar que não se deve usar. Mas eu fiz os 3 exemplo, para representar os tipos ideais e o que não é recomendavel. @JorgeB.

Comment: Excelente! +1 pela edição.

Answer (score 0):

Como já mencionado, utilize campo `DATE` e não `VARCHAR` para datas, uma opção seria fazer o agrupamento direto na consulta SQL

```
SELECT
t.user_id,
COUNT(t.user_id) as qt_dias,

CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 0 THEN 'Domingo' 
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 1 THEN 'Segunda-feira'
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 2 THEN 'Terça-feira'
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 3 THEN 'Quarta-feira'
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 4 THEN 'Quinta-feira'
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 5 THEN 'Sexta-feira'
     WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.data,'%w') = 6 THEN 'Sábado'
END as dia_semana

FROM tab t
GROUP BY dia_semana
ORDER BY t.user_id;
```

Com **[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** você extrai o dia da semana, onde *(0 = Domingo, 1 = Segunda, e etc...)*, e utilizando **[CASE WHEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)**, você compara e retorna o dia da semana no formato desejado.

**Exemplo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/069ce/12)**